# Not able to create new @index on MongoDB through spring boot application

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I am just trying to create index using below annotation on entity bean field.
**@Indexed(name = "MyCustomIndex", background = true, expireAfter = "10")**

Index was not created since  index creation is disabled by default in latest version of spring data.

So i tried to add the below line in property file 
***spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true***

but getting below error while starting applicaiton due to existing indexes . it might be trying to create the indexes which were already exist.

***nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 85 (IndexOptionsConflict): 'Index with name: already exists with a different name'***

Comment: Might be there is already an index on the same field with another name. Open your database and view the indexes of the collection having this piece of code